# Auto create individual product pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, url-rewriting

i am returning to an application I wrote a few months ago and trying to make a few minor adjustments.  I currently have a model `Product` and a catalogue page where all products are listed using an `each` loop for all entries in `Product`.

In order to attempt to keep the site secure I have put `http://.../products/...` behind a authentication login, so only users with a password can see `/products/index`, edit the product details and also see the products one at a time (show page).

I would now like to link from the page with all products listed to a page with just ONE product's details (i.e. an individual product's own page).

I am aware that I can find a product from the `Product` model using a find function for a `Product ID`, however, how do I go about automatically creating a sensible URL for this product's listing?

In summary, if I had a listing of 10 products on a page, what is the best way of enabling a user to click on the product and be routed to a page called `http://..../shop/specific_products_name`?  I have read around a bit and it appears `to_param` may be of some benefit, but I am struggling to work out a sensible means of creating these pages

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic, conventional controller setup:

First, here's the route shortcut syntax:

```
# config/routes.rb
...
resources :products
...
```

Here's the controller that loads all the Products on the `index` and just one Product on the `show`.

```
# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController 
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end   
end
```

That line in the routes file gives us these routes (among others):

- `/products` goes to `products_controller#index`
- `/products/:id` goes to `products_controller#show` with params[:id] set to the given number

The easiest way to get a pretty URL with the least amount of work is to, as you looked into, override `to_param`.

`to_param` is what Rails uses to turn a model into a representation in a url/request.

By default, it's this:

```
class Product
  def to_param
    self.id
  end
end
```

So when Rails does a Product.find() on the result of that `to_param`, `find()` turns it into an integer with `to_i`.

If `params[:id]` is `"24"`, then `Product.find(params[:id])` converts "24" to the integer 24.

But consider how `to_i` works with other examples:

```
"100".to_i                     #=> 100
"100-flux-capacitor-2000".to_i #=> 100
```

In other words, if our parameter representation of a Product is `"#{id}-the-product-name"`, `Product.find(params[:id])` will still work even though our products#show URLs look like `/products/56-ford-taurus`.

One more thing:

```
"I love the Ford Taurus".parameterize #=> "i-love-the-ford-taurus"
```

## Solution A

The easiest solution to your problem is to override to_param like this:

```
class Product
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

The benefit of this method is that you change one method in the Product model and the rest of your code Just Works.

The downside is that your URLs looks like:

```
/products/56-ford-taurus
```

Instead of:

```
/products/ford-taurus
```

## Solution B

If you want the latter example, you can maintain a `slug` column in the Products table.

Example:

```
Product
  id: 58
  name: Ford Taurus
  slug: ford-taurus
```

Then you could override to_param like this:

```
class Product
  def to_param
    slug
  end
end
```

Now, params[:id] would look like "ford-taurus".

`Product.find("ford-taurus")` wouldn't work anymore since find() wants an integer, so you could replace `Product.find(params[:id])` with `Product.find_by_slug(params[:id])`.

You'd just have to make sure every product has a unique slug.

And you can automate the slug creation process with something like:

```
class Product
  before_create :make_slug

  private
  def make_slug
    self.slug = name.parameterize
  end
end
```

That way, you just need to set the product's name on creation, save it, and its slug will become a URL friendly "whatever-the-product-name-was".

- Plus side: Your URLs now only contain the product name with no ugly product ID.
- Down side: Changing the slug a product will break URLs, which is why my before_filter example only sets the slug on creation and not any time you save the product.

Now that Rails will generate the kind of URLs you want, you can generate links to these products in a view like this:

```
# This would be in views/index.html.erb
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to product.name, product %>
<% end %>
```

Would product this sort of html for each product:

```
<a href="/products/56-ford-taurus">Ford Taurus</a> (if you used Solution A)
<a href="/products/ford-taurus">Ford Taurus</a> (if you used Solution B)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your incredibly thorough answer which does exactly what you say.  This is very useful, but doesn't do entirely what I hoped and as such I have a couple of follow on queries...(hope you don't mind)

1. Solution A is fine, ideally I would like a `/` rather than a `-` after the `id` but this causes an error?
2. Users still need to login to view products in this way which isn't my goal, I currently have `before_filter :authenticate` in my `Products Controller`, can I disable authentication for the show page only?
3. Could i shrink the URL so `/products/` isn't there?

Comment: Haha, it's cool. I obviously had too much coffee and must've misinterpreted the crux of your question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You can disable a before filter with: `before_filter :authenticate, except: :show` or `before_filter :authenticate, only: :index`. You can also pass in an array of actions, like `only: [:show, :new]`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: Cool thanks - I had a feeling there was something like that, but would have taken me ages to fiddle around trying all possibilities!

Comment: For the trailing slash, by default, if you used the `resources :products` route helper, Rails thinks `products/56/ford_taurus` is pointing to the `ford_taurus` action for the product with an id of 56 (like `/products/46/edit`). Which you probably figured out. You can just manually define your own routes in your routes.rb. Maybe something like `match "/:id" => "products#show"` would work. That combined with Solution B would make `domain.com/ford-taurus` work like you wanted, and you can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html